# Padding a hexadecimal string with zeros to a 6 character length

Tags: string, lua, formatting, padding

I have this:

```
function dec2hex(IN)
  local OUT
  OUT = string.format("%x",IN)
  return OUT
end
```

and need `IN` to have padded zeros to string length of 6.

I can't use `String.Utils` or `PadLeft`.  It's within an app called Watchmaker which uses a cut down version of Lua.

Comment: `OUT = ('0'):rep(6-#OUT)..OUT`

Comment: YES!!! That works...I've never seen rep before...and I've scoured the Lua docs.

Answer (score 5):

String formats in Lua work mostly just like in C.  So to pad a number with zeros, just use `%0n` where `n` is the number of places.  For example

```
print(string.format("%06x", 16^4-1))
```

will print `00ffff`.

See chapter 20 [The String Library](https://www.lua.org/pil/20.html) of “Programming in Lua”, the reference of [`string.format`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.format), and the C reference for the [`printf` family](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) of functions for details.

Comment: But I'm not padding a number I'm padding a hexadecimal string as the dehumanized edited version of my question I'm guessing is supposed to make clear. Thank you though. Hopefully that won't get edited out...!

Comment: @Rob Are you looking for `IN= "ffff" while #IN < 6 do IN = "0" .. IN end` then?

Comment: Ummm....what would that output be? My Lua is very poor....as you may have noticed.

Comment: Basically the above function through other means outputs a hexadecimal string which MUST be 6 characters to be read as a hex colour value so if the final value is FFFF it must be padded to 00FFFF, if FF then padded to 0000FF and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If you store your format string locally you can call the format method on to the format string and the example of @Henri results in `("%06x"):format(0xffff)`

```
print(("%06x"):format(0xffff)) -- Prints `00ffff`
```

You can write numbers in [hex format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal). It is the same as C.

Comment: To switch between left pad you can use + e.g. `("%+6x")` and for the right pad `("%-6x")`